# How can I see Gerrit environment variables passed from the gerrit trigger in Jenkins?

Tags: gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I need to see the Gerrit environment variables that are passed from the gerrit trigger in Jenkins to (in my case) a gradle build. The keys are shown [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/hudson/plugins/gerrit/trigger/hudsontrigger/GerritTriggerParameters.java). I was hoping that adding this to the build.gradle would show them:

```
ext.systemProperties = System.properties
println "All properties = ${System.properties}"
```

This prints lots of variables but not the gerrit variables. Any thoughts?

Thanks up front.

Comment: The variables are only added to the builds that are triggered by gerrit, not just any build

Comment: Under 'Build Triggers' in the Jenkins config pageI have only 'Gerrit event' checked, and within the Gerrit Trigger paneI of the config page I have 'Poll SCM' checked (and it's gets polled every minute).

Comment: Polling means it is not triggered by Gerrit, so you will not have any Gerrit variables

Comment: Thank you yes that makes sense, cheers.